# Sublime Text navigate to file in sidebar when opened with CTRL+P ("goto anything")

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Say I've got opened a project or a directory structure in Sublime Text. When I open a file with `CTRL+P`, I frequently navigate in the sidebar to the directory that contains it after opening the file, to get my bearings in a large project. It would be nice if this could be automated.

Is there a way to configure this, or a plugin for it? I wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have the sidebar expand to some file that you find with `Goto Anything`.  To do so, you can install the [SyncedSideBar](https://github.com/sobstel/SyncedSideBar) package.

> SyncedSideBar
>
> Sublime Text 2 plugin to sync project sidebar (folder view) with
>   currently active file.
>
> Sublime Text 2 highlights only those files that are already expanded.
>   **This plugin highlights all files (eg. opened with cmd+p)**.